# How can I store 256-bit integer on unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, int

I tried using the BigInteger implementation for Unity, but it still overflows(Or maybe I used in a wrong way? Im not sure also, it can only do 20 characters of ints which is like 64 bits).... This is how my thing works, I have a Hexadecimal which is has 64 characters, and then for me to do arthmetic computations, I want to convert it first into a decimal form and store it in variable.

> ```
> public BigInteger x = 0;
> ```

and then here where it overflows... HexToDecimal is a function that takes a string of Hexadecimal and returns the decimal form of that.

> x = HexToDecimal(hex);

a sample output of HexToDecimal is

> 105627842363267744400190144423808258002852957479547731009248450467191077417570

that's the ideal size of a number I want to store.
It works if I used very small numbers like hundreds thousands or something. but BitInteger kinda limits it to 20 characters only cause I tried declaring a variable like this, just to know the where BitInteger limits me

> `public BigInteger x = 10000000000000000000`

when I add another "0" there, its throws an error stating that integral is too large

Comment: Show how you are using it with `BigInteger` and how how it overflows

Comment: I just declared a variable with a bitinteger type. like "public BitInteger x;"

Comment: Edit your question and add that. Also show why you think it id overflowing. Your current code doesn't show a working code or overflow proof

Comment: done editting :)

Answer (score 5):

The way you've instantiated your `BigInteger` is a [convenience method for smaller numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5) (see "instantiating a BigInteger" -- I can't seem to link to it directly). This means that you're *actually* creating an int32 or an int64 and then converting it to a BigInteger (so it has to be able to fit into the limited size of those types).

To truly take advantage of BigInteger's arbitrary size, you probably want to use [`BigInteger.Parse(String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268231(v=vs.110).aspx). This method will return a BigInteger for a numeric String (and it must be a numeric string as defined by the current system culture -- nothing else except a possible leading negative symbol) This method should work perfectly fine in Unity as it's part of the C# standard lib.

So, for your `HexToDecimal` example, assuming it returns a string you'd use it like

```
x = BigInteger.Parse(HexToDecimal(hex));
```